# Spring Boot neo4j infinite loop

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

I have a Spring Boot App with a neo4j database and have a problem with the neo4j repository fetching nested data and creating a loop.

I have a node `Person`. A `Person` can send access requests to another `Person`. When I fetch a `Person`, I want to get the data of all the access requests TO and FROM other `Person`s. The model looks like this:

```
@Data
@Node
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String email;

    @Relationship(type = "ACCESS_REQUESTED", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    @JsonProperty("requested_contacts")
    private List<AccessRequested> requestedContacts;

    @Relationship(type = "ACCESS_REQUESTED", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    @JsonProperty("contact_requests")
    private List<AccessRequested> contactRequests;
}

@RelationshipProperties
@Data
public class AccessRequested {
    @RelationshipId
    @GeneratedValue
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @TargetNode
    private Person person;

    private String reason;
}
```

Now I am using the Neo4jRepository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

And I am calling `findById(Long id)`

The problem is that when I fetch a Person that has sent the request to another person, it creates an infinite loop:

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "requested_contacts": [],
    "contact_requests": [
        {
            "person": {
                "id": 5,
                "requested_contacts": [
                    {
                        "person": {
                            "id": 13,
                            "requested_contacts": [],
                            "contact_requests": [
                                {
                                    "person": {
                                        "id": 5,
                                        "contact_cards": [],
                                        "requested_contacts": [
                                            {
                                                "person": {
                                                    "id": 13,
                                                    "requested_contacts": [],
                                                    "contact_requests": [
                                                        {
                                                            "person": {
                                                                "id": 5,
                                                                "contact_cards": [],
                                                                "requested_contacts": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "person": {
                                                                            "id": 13,
                                                                                    …….
```

How can I fix that? I want to fetch the full person on top level, but the nested persons should only contain id and email.

Comment: What is the repository method you are calling?

Comment: `findById(Long id)`

Comment: Add a method `Person findById(Long id, @Depth int depth);`, in the repository and pass this a depth of 1. Or you wanna write a custom query